# A translation for "A part for understanding the whole" - "ad res" or "ad rem"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

When translating "A part for understanding / to understand the whole," can I use a construction with "ad res" / "ad rem", e.g., "pars ad res tota intelligendas"?

I want to use it similar to a proverb, like pars pro toto, so there is not much context. Maybe a better phrasing would be: "A part that contributes to understanding the whole". The metaphor would be a puzzle, where we need to put parts together to form the whole image. I would still like to put emphasis on "understanding".

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen *ad* + gerundive used in this way. And *pars* is also not commonly used with *ad*. If you look at the grammar books, you'll find claims that *ad* + gerund(ive) is sometimes used to denote purpose, but look at the [examples](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gerund-and-gerundive) that Allen & Greenough offer:

- Vīvis nōn ad dēpōnendam sed ad cōnfīrmandam audāciam. (Cat. 1.4)
- nactus aditūs ad ea cōnanda (B. C. 1.31)

Here we have an adverbial use, and a use with *aditus*, which is a verbal noun that carries around its own *ad*. I cannot see how we can justify *pars ad* from this. Could we make it adverbial? Perhaps: *pars quam tibi ostendo ad totam rem patefaciendam*? Sure, I think this would work, but it would not help you much, since you are looking for an isolated phrase without this sort of context.

But what would fit your purpuse much better and sound more natural, in my opinion, would be a relative clause: *Pars qua tota res intellegitur* (or *intellegi potest*), or *pars ex qua tota res patebit* etc. – you get the idea.